# Javascript Display Multiline

Tags: javascript

I have a string that looks like this:

```
const multiLine = "This is line 1\nThis is line2\nThis is line3";
```

How do I display it to browser as multi-line at the `\n` breakpoints?

Comment: I tried putting it in string literals like this: ``${ multiLine }``

Comment: `multiline.replace(/\n/g,'<br>')`

Answer (score 4):

You can use `css` `white-space` set to `pre` at element where `.textContent` is set

```js
const multiLine = "This is line 1\nThis is line2\nThis is line3";

document.querySelector("div").textContent = multiLine;
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great too.

Answer (score 2):

HTML doesn't interpret `\n` as a linebreak. You can use `<br>` instead.

A simple replace should do the job.

```
let multiLine = "This is line 1\nThis is line2\nThis is line3";
multiline = multiline.replace(/\n/g, '<br>');
```

Using a regular expression match to find all all matching properties. `/\n/` is essential the same as `\n`. The `g` in `/\n/g` tells it to find all matching properties so it'll replace all matches and not just the first.

Comment: Thank you, I'll accept this as answer when it lets me

Comment: @user3254198 _"HTML doesn't interpret \n as a linebreak."_ If `white-space` is set to `pre` at element `style` attribute or `css` the `\n` should be rendered as a newline character.